# Sum(distinct metric) in apache druid

Tags: druid

how do we write sum(distinct col) in druid ? if i try to write in druid, it says plans can't be build, but same is possible in Druid.  I tried to convert to subquery approach, but my inner query returns lot of item level data, hence timing out.

Answer (score 0):

The distinct count or sum is not something which is by default supported by druid.

There are actually several methods which give you a similar result.

**Option 1. Theta Sketch extension (recommended)**

If you enable the Theta Sketch extension (See https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/datasketches-theta.html) you can use this to get the same result.

Example:

```
{
    "queryType": "groupBy",
    "dataSource": "hits",
    "intervals": [
        "2020-08-14T11:00:00.000Z/2020-08-14T12:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "dimensions": [],
    "granularity": "all",
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "type": "cardinality",
            "name": "col",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "type": "default",
                    "dimension": "domain",
                    "outputType": "string",
                    "outputName": "domain"
                }
            ],
            "byRow": false,
            "round": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Result:

```
+--------+
| domain | 
+--------+
| 22     | 
+--------+
```

**Option 2: cardinality**

The cardinality() aggregation computes the cardinality of a set of Apache Druid (incubating) dimensions, using HyperLogLog to estimate the cardinality.

Example:

```
{
    "queryType": "groupBy",
    "dataSource": "hits",
    "intervals": [
        "2020-08-14T11:00:00.000Z/2020-08-14T12:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "dimensions": [],
    "granularity": "all",
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "type": "cardinality",
            "name": "domain",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "type": "default",
                    "dimension": "domain",
                    "outputType": "string",
                    "outputName": "domain"
                }
            ],
            "byRow": false,
            "round": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Response:

```
+-----------------+
| domain          | 
+-----------------+
| 22.119017166376 | 
+-----------------+
```

**Option 3. use hyperUnique**

This option requires that you keep track of the counts at indexation time. If you have applied this, you can use this in your query:

```
{
    "queryType": "groupBy",
    "dataSource": "hits",
    "intervals": [
        "2020-08-14T11:00:00.000Z/2020-08-14T12:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "dimensions": [],
    "granularity": "all",
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "type": "hyperUnique",
            "name": "domain",
            "fieldName": "domain",
            "isInputHyperUnique": false,
            "round": false
        }
    ],
    "context": {
        "groupByStrategy": "v2"
    }
}
```

As I have no hyperUnique metric in my data set, I have no exact example response.

This page explains this method very well: https://blog.mshimul.com/getting-unique-counts-from-druid-using-hyperloglog/

**Conclusion**

In my opinion the Theta Sketch extension is the best and most easy way to get the result. Please read the documentation carefully.

If you are an PHP user you could take a look at this, maybe it helps:

- https://github.com/level23/druid-client#hyperunique
- https://github.com/level23/druid-client#cardinality
- https://github.com/level23/druid-client#distinctcount